# Entering data at a specific ID where as Auto Increment is ON (i.e Identity =TRUE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

how to insert value at a specific index in id Column where as `Id` Field is auto increment

for Example in may case say columns are ID and Name

```
   ID                    Name
======================================== 
   2                     Austin   
   3                     Peter    
   4                     Albness   
   22                    Sidhu   
   23                    deepika     
   24                    Shahrukh
```

Where `Id` is Auto incremented here in my case I have deleted the `Id` 1,4,5,6 to onward 21 and now I want to add the new name at `Id=1` remember again Id is auto_increment (i.e `Identity=TRUE` in the property )

How do I Accomplish it

Comment: Why bother trying to fill the gaps, just let SQL manage the Identities, that's what the auto increment is designed to do. You're not supposed to go back in and fill the gaps. If you are determined you would have to turn the IDENTITY INSERT ON and OFF

Comment: @tanner to make it uniform,in case if gaps are of thousands then it looks strange ....

Comment: @tanner u mean to say  for that instant of time i want to insert make it OFF and then  make ON after i insert at the desired position or ID ???

Comment: looks strange to who? that doesn't really sound like a good enough reason to implement such functionality

Comment: @tanner, To me and everyone who sees the databases ...

Comment: If that's your only reason, it's more hassle than it's worth. You may want to just look at reseeding the identity column on a regular basis instead of manually doing it: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/01/sql-server-reseed-identity-of-table-table-missing-identity-values-gap-in-identity-column/

Answer (score 0):

To insert ID value on a table just do that

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database. [ owner. ] ] { table } { ON | OFF }
```

Example your table name is People it should be

```
INSERT INTO People(ID,NAME) VALUES(3,'Felicio')
```

PS: to insert indentity value you also need to explicity the columns names and order as in previous example.

Answer (score 0):

For all use cases I can think of, just leaving the gaps seems to be the simpler and safer solution. End users should not see these IDs, and DBAs should be OK with it.

If it's such a big deal, I'd still rather have a DBA manually run a "cleanup" script in a maintenance window than add complexity to production code.

Answer (score 0):

`Id` is either [surrogate](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) or natural key.

- If it's surrogate, it doesn't have a meaning, and therefore gaps don't matter.
- If it's natural, it shouldn't have been auto-increment in the first place.